# Any open source, fast H263 decoder library for ARM9 than ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, decoder

Is there Any open source, fast H263 decoder library for ARM9 than ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ported the Telenor H.263 decoder to ARM9.  It seemed to run fine.  Telenor doesn't distribute it any more, but the files [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid2F5F0C7648ABEDC82AD1F863C42413C43E232EC2.aspx?s=malloc#L158) look like what I used.

Comment: I didn't benchmark it against anything - the main reason for choosing it was that it was really small.  I do remember that I/O was the constraint for frame rate.

Comment: happen to have this laying around anywhere? the link is broken now.

Comment: morisette, this looks like the encoder and decoder source: http://www.linuxmedialabs.com/Downloads/LSI/h263/H.263/telenor/ The filenames and README text match my recollection. There are probably better options by now - like using just the Baseline Profile with H.264. There must be an optimized version floating around. But in any event,  good luck!

Answer (score 1):

may be x263 from Xirlink?

Answer (score 0):

http://freshmeat.net/projects/helixplayer

http://freshmeat.net/projects/mediastreamer

http://sourceforge.net/projects/h263/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpeg4dec/

If any suits you say it!